# copy / restore - mongo db

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql

I am new to mongo db. I got a web application and "data" folder from my client. In the data folder, there are many folders. I installed mongo db and created a test db. If I want to use the data that I got my client, do I have to copy and paste those files or I have to create those dbs and use import option. Please help me.

Comment: What format is the data that you got from your client - is it a MongoDB dump, or some text or XML or a spreadsheet? Is it structured in any way? What do you want to do with it once you've imported it into Mongo?

Comment: I tried copy and paste option. and tried show dbs command in the mongo window.

Comment: file type NS file, 0 file, 1 file

Comment: Right, so it's a detached MongoDB that you want to mount into your Mongo instance to query it?

Comment: Yes, can you tell me command to mount to my Mongo instance

Comment: any help to mount detachedMongoDB to my mongo instance ? thanks.

Comment: By detachedMongoDB what specifically are you referring to in this context?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the files you got from your client were mongodb data files.  If that's the case you should be able to just startup mongod using those data files as-is.  To do this, first you should shut down the running mongod and delete its existing data files (by default located in /data/db).  Then you can copy the data files you got from the client into the data directory that mongod is using and start it up again.

In addition, you might or might not have to include the --directoryperdb flag, depending on how the data files you received are structured.  You said that within the data folder you got there were several subfolders.  Does each subfolder just contain files with the same name as the folder followed by . or .ns?  If so, then you have one folder for each database's data files and should start with the --directoryperdb flag.  If not, and you instead have one folder with .ns and . files for multiple dbnames, then you should not use the --directoryperdb flag.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. yes, sub folders have database files. I am trying to use --directoryperdb command but it is not recognizing for reason. I tried like this : mongod --directoryperdb "c:\data" but it didn't work

Comment: You'll need to use --dbpath to specify the path to the data files, --directoryperdb doesn't take any arguments, it just tells mongod to expect the data files to be in a certain layout.